# Eclipse Oxygen and Scala IDE 4.7 crashes with play framework 2.6.6 project in workspace

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide, playframework-2.6

There are two scenarios where my eclipse ide or scala ide (downloaded directly from scala site) crashes when play/maven project is in workspace.

Here's the issue:

Upon reboot of eclipse/scala ide it says:
"An Error has occurred. See the log file /.metadata/.log"

Here's the content of that log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui 4 0 2017-11-14 12:05:24.743
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1675)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.stop(TasksUiPlugin.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:828)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui.compatibility.CommonColors.<clinit>(CommonColors.java:28)
    ... 18 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin.stop(TasksUiPlugin.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1675)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui.compatibility.CommonColors.<clinit>(CommonColors.java:28)
    ... 18 more
```

I tested it with both ScalaIDE and Eclipse

1) Install Scala IDE 4.7. import existing play/maven project. Notice bunch of scala complier errors in IDE Error Log. Restart and you see eclipse can't boot same workspace. It can boot other workspaces. Even if I remove all eclipse files (.settings, .classpath, .project) from play-maven project it crashes. Only soln is to remove .metadata from workspace and re-import project. But issue happens again after next restart.

2) Install Eclipse Oxygen. import existing play/maven project. Install Scala IDE 4.7 plugin which requires eclipse to restart. Upon restart it crashes for that workspace. Same workaround as 1.

PS - as I mentioned on top, eclipse/scala-id start up fine if I choose any other workspace which doesn't have play-maven project inside.

Let me know if I need to share any other detail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "install eclipse oxygen" but I think in case of this sort of problem is better to download Scala IDE from here http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html as zip and unpack it. Hope it helps

Comment: eclipse oxygen is their latest version of eclipse. If you read 1) in my description, you'll know I already tried scalaIde 4.7 directly

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solution?

Comment: @GeorgedeLemos they say 4.7.1-RC3 supposed to have a fix. I have yet to try. http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html

Comment: @nir tried that but no good result... I will wait for an eclipse IDE fix